# T-SQL distinct count query...can it be optimized with an EXISTS or something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to make this query run faster (meaning take less reads/IO from SQL Server).  The logic essentially is

1. I count distinct values from a column
2. if there is any more than 1 distinct value, it is considered as existing
3. List is built with the name of the column and a 1 or 0 if it is existing

I would like to do something with EXISTS (in t-sql that terminates the scan of the table/index if SQL Server finds the match to the EXISTS predicate).  I am not sure if that is possible in this query.

Note: I am not looking for answers like is there an index on the table...well beyond that :)

```
    with SomeCTE as
            (                   
    select 
    count(distinct(ColumnA)) as ColumnA,        
    count(distinct(ColumnB)) as ColumnB,        
    count(distinct(ColumnC)) as ColumnC
from VERYLARGETABLE
        )
select 'NameOfColumnA', case when ColumnA > 1 then 1 else 0 end from SomeCTE
UNION ALL
select 'NameOfColumnB', case when ColumnB > 1 then 1 else 0 end from SomeCTE
UNION ALL
select 'NameOfColumnC', case when ColumnC > 1 then 1 else 0 end from SomeCTE
```

Just to copy what I posted below in the comments.
So after testing this solution.  It makes the queries run "faster".  To give two examples..one query went from 50 seconds to 3 seconds.  Another went from 9+ minutes (stopped running it) went down to 1min03seconds.  Also I am missing indexes (so according to DTA should run 14% faster)  also I am running this in the SQL Azure DB (where you are being throttled drastically in terms of I/O, CPU and tempddb memory)...very nice solution all around.  One downside is that min/max does not work on bit columns, but those can be converted.

Comment: `if there is any more than 1 distinct value, it is considered as existing` You're not interested in the count except to know that it's 0,1, or greater than 1, right?  What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: The columns are strings.  Yes you are correct...0 or 1, I would of just done an exists.

Comment: Are we to assume no indexes on the individual columns?

Comment: @Martin all those columns are indexed/have statistics.  It is read-only so, I went overboard on indexing...this is just one query out of many that are run, so there might be indexes as well that do not pertain to this query (or could confuse the optimizer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the datatype of the columns allow aggregate functions and if there are indexes, one for every column, this will be fast:

```
SELECT 'NameOfColumnA' AS ColumnName,
       CASE WHEN MIN(ColumnA) < MAX(ColumnA)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END AS result
FROM VERYLARGETABLE 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'NameOfColumnB',
       CASE WHEN MIN(ColumnB) < MAX(ColumnB)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END 
FROM VERYLARGETABLE 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'NameOfColumnC' 
       CASE WHEN MIN(ColumnC) < MAX(ColumnC)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END 
FROM VERYLARGETABLE ;
```

Comment: Nice idea using the MIN/MAX to compare

Comment: Going to test this now...this looks promising.

Comment: So after testing this solution.  It makes the queries run "faster".  To give two examples..one query went from 50 seconds to 3 seconds.  Another went from 9+ minutes (stopped running it) went down to 1min03seconds.  Also I am missing indexes (so according to DTA should run 14% faster)  also I am running this in the SQL Azure DB (where you are being throttled drastically in terms of I/O, CPU and tempddb memory)...very nice solution all around.  One downside is that min/max does not work on bit columns, but those can be converted.

Comment: @BartCzernicki - converting means an index won't be used. For those `SELECT TOP 1 Flag FROM Table ORDER BY Flag ASC|DESC` would be better.